How to get debuginfod for GDB MSYS2?
I have been trying to run GDP to debug a Tcl C extension using the command gdb tclsh - but the MSYS2 version of GDB says that Support for debuginfod is not compiled into GDB. and outputs Reading symbols from tclsh.exe...  (No debugging symbols found in tclsh.exe) so it doesn't work.
I am trying to copy the details in this GitHub comment - but I am doing it on Windows not Linux and I can't find anything on debuginfod for MSYS2 or Windows, there doesn't see to be anything on it online.
Is there any way I can get it for my version of GDB so it can work like it does in the comment I linked?
Here is the console output if you want to see it:
GNU gdb (GDB) 15.1
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from tclsh.exe...
(No debugging symbols found in tclsh.exe)
[New Thread 23524.0x78e4]
[New Thread 23524.0x5a50]
[New Thread 23524.0x3394]
[New Thread 23524.0x4cd4]
[Thread 23524.0x4cd4 exited with code 0]
[Thread 23524.0x3394 exited with code 0]
[Thread 23524.0x5a50 exited with code 0]
[Thread 23524.0x78e4 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 23524) exited normally]
(gdb) set debuginfod enabled on
Support for debuginfod is not compiled into GDB.
(gdb)

What I compiled:
Building Tkhtml 3

COMPILE = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -g -DUSE_TCL_STUBS=1 -DUSE_TK_STUBS=1 -IC:/Users/billa/OneDrive/Documents/test1/htmlwidget/tkhtml/src/ -O -
TCLSH   = tclsh


$(COMPILE) -c C:/Users/billa/OneDrive/Documents/test1/htmlwidget/tkhtml//src/htmldraw.c -o htmldraw.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared  htmlparse.o htmldraw.o htmltcl.o htmlimage.o htmltree.o htmltagdb.o css.o cssprop.o csssearch.o htmlstyle.o mlutil.o cssparser.o htmlPs.o "/mingw64/lib/libtclstub86.a"  "/mingw64/lib/libtkstub86.a"  -LC:/Tcl/lib -o Tkhtml30g.dll
strip Tkhtml30g.dll
echo 'package ifneeded Tkhtml 3.0 [list load [file join $dir Tkhtml30g.dll]]' > pkgIndex.tcl


Even if you get debuginfod compiled into gdb, it would still not work for Windows executables, as it only works for ELF executables on Linux.

Just in case, you know what debuginfod is, right? You don't need if you have debug symbols in the exe.

Turns out that strip Tkhtml30g.dll was removing all the debug symbols from the shared library (as @cyan-ogilvie kindly pointed out), so I edited the Makefile to change the strip value to true and after that it seems to be working fine.

I only use Linux so I'm not familiar with any Windows specific debugging issues, but from the gdb output you posted I can see that the tclsh.exe you're using doesn't have debug symbols.  If you're building the tclsh.exe using the unix-style tooling (configure, make, etc.) which I seem to remember doing using MinGW in the distant past, then adding --enable-symbols to the configure will turn on that debug info.
But that's only needed if you want to step through the source of Tcl itself.  If you're just wanting to step through the code of your own extension then it's sufficient to just turn on debug info when compiling your extension.  If you're using gcc from the MinGW toolchain to build your extension, then add the -g switch to turn on the debug symbols (or -ggdb3 if your compiler supports it, for much more extensive gdb support like the values of macros and enums).
Once your extension has debug symbols, starting gdb with gdb tclsh as you were doing, adding a breakpoint at the function in your extension you're interested in (say y when gdb warns you that the symbol doesn't exist yet), running tcl (r), loading your package in the tclsh REPL and calling the function you're debugging should work (here demonstrated by breaking on the capply_cmd symbol in the jitc extension, in a tclsh without debug symbols):
[cyan@p1 ~]% gdb tclsh
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04.2) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from tclsh...
(No debugging symbols found in tclsh)
(gdb) b capply_cmd
Function "capply_cmd" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (capply_cmd) pending.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/tclsh 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
% package require jitc
0.5.5
% jitc::capply {code {OBJCMD(foo) {return TCL_OK;}}} foo

Breakpoint 1, capply_cmd (cdata=0x5555556314d0, interp=0x55555556a9d0, objc=3, objv=0x555555578090) at ./generic/jitc.c:1132
1132    {
(gdb) l
1127
1128    //}}}
1129    // Stubs API }}}
1130    // Script API {{{
1131    static int capply_cmd(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[]) //{{{
1132    {
1133            int                             code = TCL_OK;
1134            Tcl_ObjCmdProc* proc = NULL;
1135
1136            if (objc < 3) {
(gdb) 


I am absolutely sure I compiled it with debug symbols - recompiled it as I was writing this. The example I listed doesn't seem to have this problem, I don't know why? I added what I compiled to the question.

Well, although -g is in the COMPILE variable, it (the COMPILE variable) isn't used, so the -g flag isn't supplied to x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc when it is actually run.  Additionally, running strip Tkhtml30g.dll removes any debug symbols that were there.
